# Apache, mod_wsgi, and Pandas import error, unable to import dependencies Numpy due to error

Tags: pandas, apache, numpy, flash, mod-wsgi

I'm able to deploy the flask app without the Pandas library, so I don't think something is wrong with how I set up the server. Additionally, I'm able to run my flask app with pandas with Flask's development server, so I think it might be something to do with mod_wsgi.
I'm using  Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured.

I'm unable to import pandas, and trying to do so through mod_wsgi generates this error.

```
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792041 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]     "Unable to import required dependencies:\\n" + "\\n".join(missing_dependencies)
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792058 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792063 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] numpy:
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792066 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792068 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792071 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792074 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792101 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] - Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792105 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] - If you have already done that, then:
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792108 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]   1. Check that you expected to use Python3.6 from "/usr/bin/python3",
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792111 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792114 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.4" you're trying to use.
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792117 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]   2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792120 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792123 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      - how you installed Python
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792126 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      - how you installed numpy
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792129 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      - your operating system
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792131 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792134 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]      - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792137 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792140 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] - If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792143 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]   (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792146 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792149 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792152 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792155 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252]
[Mon Nov 18 08:03:25.792157 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 13940:tid 140279706347264] [remote 73.71.92.203:61252] Original error was: /var/www/app/KENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

I'm running python 3.6.8, pandas is 0.25.1 and numpy is 1.17.4.

Comment: I've currently circumvented the problem by calling a subprocess, but ultimately I'd want to the file importing pandas as a module.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably due to [SELinux](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#secure-variants-of-unix) restrictions.

Note that even if you manage to convince your system to load the shared libraries, using numpy under mod_wsgi is known to not work because numpy does not really [support python sub-interpreters](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8559)